# Displaying lot of pixmaps with a QLabel under them on a QGraphicsPixmap

Tags: qt, text, widget, icons, clickable

I need a widget where i can place a variety of clickable icons and under those icons some text using QLabel.

This is an image: [image]

I know this will need some tweaking and sub-classing. What would be the best appropiate way to do this? I know that those clickable icons will be displayed on a QGraphicsView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a QGraphicsView.

Here is a sample for a clickable pixmap:

```
ClickablePixmap::ClickablePixmap( QGraphicsItem* itemParent )
    : QObject(0)
    , QGraphicsPixmapItem(itemParent)
    , m_pressed(false)
{
    setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable |
             QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable |
             QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsGeometryChanges |
             QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresParentOpacity
             );
    setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt::LeftButton);
    setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
}

void ClickablePixmap::mouseReleaseEvent( QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* event )
{
    setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
    m_pressed = false;
    update();
    if( boundingRect().contains(event->pos()) )
        emit clicked();
    event->accept();
}

void ClickablePixmap::mousePressEvent( QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* event )
{
    setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
    m_pressed = true;
    update();
    QGraphicsPixmapItem::mousePressEvent(event);
}

void ClickablePixmap::paint( QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option, QWidget* widget )
{
    Q_UNUSED(option);
    Q_UNUSED(widget);

    QRect rect(0,0, boundingRect().width(), boundingRect().height());

    // Create the pushed effet
    if( m_pressed ) {
        rect.adjust(2,2,-2,-2);
    }
    painter->drawPixmap(rect, pixmap());
}
```

The next thing to do is to embed this widget into a container widget with a:

```
QVBoxLayout
```

Then you can add your QLabel underneath.